# \dotfill with minimal length

Tags: dotfill

I want to build a \dotfill command where I can specify a minimum length.
I have tried:

```
\makebox[0.88em]{\dotfill}\dotfill
```

As the standard spacing of dotfill is 0.44em, so I get exactly two dots. However, there is a slightly bigger spacing between the first two dots and the dots from the second \dotfill command.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can copy the definition of `\dotfill` replacing `\hfill` by skip with a larger natural size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\def\dotfill{%
%  \leavevmode
%  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
%  \kern\z@}
%  \MakeRobust\dotfill

\DeclareRobustCommand\mydotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hbox to.44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip .88em plus 1fill
  \kern0pt }


\begin{document}

1 a\dotfill b

2 a\dotfill b\hspace{0pt  plus 1filll}c

{\parfillskip=.5\textwidth minus .5\textwidth

3 a\dotfill b

}

4 a\mydotfill b

5 a\mydotfill b\hspace{0pt  plus 1filll}c

{\parfillskip=.5\textwidth minus .5\textwidth

6 a\mydotfill b

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

That is a XY problem. David answer solved exactly what you asked (fix a minimun of dots, then +1) but not what you want (find a good solution for dot lines with 0-1 dots).

My crystal ball said that fix a minimum of dots is not that what you want, because force things in this way can produce a big `Overfull \hbox` (see black part of the MWE).

What my crystal ball cannot see is what other solution could you consider good for these cases, because it depends a lot of contents and personal preferences.

One simple solution could be enclose "a" and/or "b" in `\parbox`es, to ensure that that a+b will not take more than `\linewidth-0.88em`.

Another more complex (it need two runs!), is check if the width of a+b is smaller that this (taking at least b as argument of the macro) so you can use the standard `\dotfill` but otherwise do ... what you consider better. Just as example, the fix in the MWE is move the "b" part to the next line with a half dotted line.

The MWE also show that omitting the curly braces (`{}`) will take as first argument only the next character, so when "b part" is a word or sentence, it can produce wrong results.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a6paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{linegoal,xcolor,lipsum}
\parindent0pt\parskip0pt
\newlength\ihave
\newlength\remain
\newlength\ineed

\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mydotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hbox to.44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip .88em plus 1fill
  \kern0pt }

No argument (fake \verb-\dotfill-):

\rule{.75\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill b\par
\rule{.85\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill b\par
\rule{.95\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill b\par

\rule{.75\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill basic\par
\rule{.85\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill basic\par
\rule{.95\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill basic\par

\renewcommand\mydotfill[1]{%
\settowidth{\ihave}{#1}%
\setlength{\remain}{\dimexpr\linegoal}%
\setlength{\ineed}{\dimexpr\ihave+.88em}%
\ifdim\remain>\ineed \dotfill#1\else\\[-1ex]%
\mbox{}\hfill$\vdots$\dotfill#1\fi} 

\color{blue}

Argument  is next character   % better with curly braces ...

\rule{.75\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill b\par 
\rule{.85\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill b\par
\rule{.95\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill b\par 

\color{red}
But it should not :  % ...  because this

\rule{.75\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill basic\par 
\rule{.85\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill basic\par
\rule{.95\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill basic\par 

 \color{magenta}
Argument  is the next word/setence:

\rule{.75\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill{basic}\par 
\rule{.85\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill{basic}\par
\rule{.95\linewidth}{1.5ex} \mydotfill{basic approach method}\par 


\end{document}
```